# Why is "birthday" one word as opposed to two? "Wedding day" or "graduation day" are two

Tags: orthography, compounds, spacing

A birthday is the day of your birth, much like graduation day and wedding day.  Why is *birthday* one word?

Comment: Age. (Of the word, that is.) No really, that's all there is to it.

Comment: There is further information surrounding Reg's answer [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_compound) and [here](http://www.wilbers.com/part24.htm). I've lost the reference I had that stated that _compounds usually start off as two- (or three-) word collocations, then often develop into the hyphenated form, and finally into a solid form. The process tends to be quicker in the US. Transitions don't take place at an instant in time, so dual or triple spellings may be acceptable. Some compounds, often for obvious reasons, don't evolve in this way._

Comment: Unlike "wedding day," a birthday isn't necessarily the day of your birth; it's the _anniversary_ of your birth.